# How does ply.lex extract the regular expression from each token definition function?

Tags: python

I was really surprised by the fact that the token function definitions for ply.lex just contain the regex's floating there, without actually being returned as a return value or anything.

Here's an example:

```
 def t_INITIAL_TOKENNAME(token):

      r"[h]+"

      return token
```

I wanted to understand how this actually works, so I started looking at lex.py...

Here is some of the source code of ply.lex, taken from lex.py of ply3.4:

```
# Build the master regular expressions
for state in stateinfo:
    regex_list = []

    # Add rules defined by functions first
    for fname, f in linfo.funcsym[state]:
        line = func_code(f).co_firstlineno
        file = func_code(f).co_filename
        regex_list.append("(?P<%s>%s)" % (fname,f.__doc__))
        if debug:
            debuglog.info("lex: Adding rule %s -> '%s' (state '%s')",fname,f.__doc__, state)

    # Now add all of the simple rules
    for name,r in linfo.strsym[state]:
        regex_list.append("(?P<%s>%s)" % (name,r))
        if debug:
            debuglog.info("lex: Adding rule %s -> '%s' (state '%s')",name,r, state)

    regexs[state] = regex_list
```

What exactly is going on in the following line? It seems like the crucial line where lex is extracting the regex from each token definition, but I don't know what it's doing...

```
 regex_list.append("(?P<%s>%s)" % (fname,f.__doc__))
```

I kind of see the fprintf formatting going on here, but I don't see how the "(?P<%s>%s)" contains the regex of interest when the %s's are replaced with fname and f.**doc**.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a function (or class, or module) in Python, if the first thing is a string, it becomes the `__doc__` attribute of the thing:

```
>>> def f(a,b):
...     """Adds a and b."""
...     return a+b
...
>>> f.__doc__
'Adds a and b.'
```

ply.lex uses this feature of Python.  You define the regex pattern (which is really just a string) as the first thing in the body of the function, and it is accessible as the `__doc__` attribute of the function.